# Get individual query parameters from Uri

Tags: c#, .net, uri

I have a uri string like: http://example.com/file?a=1&b=2&c=string%20param

Is there an existing function that would convert query parameter string into a dictionary same way as ASP.NET Context.Request does it.

I'm writing a console app and not a web-service so there is no Context.Request to parse the URL for me.

I know that it's pretty easy to crack the query string myself but I'd rather use a FCL function is if exists.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Use this:

```
string uri = ...;
string queryString = new System.Uri(uri).Query;
var queryDictionary = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
```

This code by Tejs isn't the 'proper' way to get the query string from the URI:

```
string.Join(string.Empty, uri.Split('?').Skip(1));
```

Comment: Note that `Uri.Query` will only work on absolute Uri. On relative one it throws an `InvalidOperationExeception`.

Comment: Once you get `Query` from `Uri`, you can use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query)` to get name value collection

Answer (score 122):

You can use:

```
var queryString = url.Substring(url.IndexOf('?')).Split('#')[0]
System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)

Comment: But you'll need to add a reference to `System.Web.dll`.

Comment: As another answer say, ParseQueryString will add 'http://example.com/file?a' as the first key.

Comment: Updated with new code. Strangely enough, this answer seems to be very popular.

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind, ParseQueryString ALWAYS does a UrlDecode when parsing, which is fine as long as you don't have anything relying on one-to-one likeness, like say a signature algorithm in a SAML Redirect binding, which calculates the signature AFTER encoding on the other side, etc.

Comment: `Split('#')[0]` will return the left side of the real or imaginary _fragment_. Here's the spec concerning placement of the _fragment_ with respect to the _query_: [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.2)

Answer (score 25):

This should work:

```
string url = "http://example.com/file?a=1&b=2&c=string%20param";
string querystring = url.Substring(url.IndexOf('?'));
System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection parameters = 
   System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring);
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx). Not the exact collectiontype you are looking for, but nevertheless useful.

**Edit:** Apparently, if you supply the complete url to `ParseQueryString` it will add 'http://example.com/file?a' as the first key of the collection. Since that is probably not what you want, I added the substring to get only the relevant part of the url.

Answer (score 16):

I had to do this for a modern windows app. I used the following:

```
public static class UriExtensions
{
    private static readonly Regex _regex = new Regex(@"[?&](\w[\w.]*)=([^?&]+)");

    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> ParseQueryString(this Uri uri)
    {
        var match = _regex.Match(uri.PathAndQuery);
        var paramaters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        while (match.Success)
        {
            paramaters.Add(match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        return paramaters;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ross Dargan: this is a nice solution but I'd suggest creating the regex object with `RegexOptions.Compiled`, as per [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zbs0h2f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), since it is static and intended to be reused.

Comment: I updated the regex to `@"[?&](\w[\w.]*)=([^?&]+)"` since `[|?]&` also matches `|` and `[^?|^&]` matches any char but `?` / `|` / `^` and `&`.

Comment: This throws an exception if the query parameter is used more than once. i.e. "?Arg=foo&Arg=bar"

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.parsequerystring.aspx) It'll give you a `NameValueCollection` instead of a dictionary, but should still do what you need.

The other option is to use `string.Split()`.

```
    string url = @"http://example.com/file?a=1&b=2&c=string%20param";
    string[] parts = url.Split(new char[] {'?','&'});
    ///parts[0] now contains http://example.com/file
    ///parts[1] = "a=1"
    ///parts[2] = "b=2"
    ///parts[3] = "c=string%20param"
```

Answer (score 13):

For isolated projects, where dependencies must be kept to a minimum, I found myself using this implementation:

```
var arguments = uri.Query
  .Substring(1) // Remove '?'
  .Split('&')
  .Select(q => q.Split('='))
  .ToDictionary(q => q.FirstOrDefault(), q => q.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault());
```

Do note, however, that I do **not** handle encoded strings of any kind, as I was using this in a controlled setting, where encoding issues would be a coding error on the server side that should be fixed.

Comment: The returned parameters are not correctly decoded.

Comment: Which is exactly what I write just beneath the code @user2864740? :) Tried to emphasize it a bit more now.

Answer (score 11):

In a single line of code:

```
string xyz = Uri.UnescapeDataString(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString()).Get("XYZ"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Azure offers a framework that makes it easy to perform this.
http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-services/iOS/v2/Classes/MSTable.html#//api/name/readWithQueryString:completion:

Answer (score -2):

You could reference System.Web in your console application and then look for the Utility functions that split the URL parameters.