# Getting values from any URL

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parsing, url

I have this url : http://localhost:49500/Learning/Chapitre.aspx?id=2

How can I get just the value of `id` in this url ?

Comment: Are you parsing the URL as a string, or are you running code from making a request to that URL?

Comment: I have another page that redirect to this page

Comment: This was asked and answerd at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884551/get-individual-query-parameters-from-uri

Comment: that doesn't really answer the question, although I'll assume the latter.  IN that case, Patricker's answer is correct.

Comment: The question should probably have been phrased a little differently, I think it was a little confusing.  You were trying to get the a query string value that had been passed to the CURRENT page, it wasn't that you just had a URL as a string laying around.  I would probably go back and edit the question so other people can benefit from it more easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access all the query strings through the `Request.QueryString()` array:

`Request.QueryString("id")` will give you the `2`

Comment: try using `Request.QueryString["id"]` note the square brackets

Answer (score 2):

Despite my own comment saying it has been answered, here is the code.

```
Dim idval As String = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString("http://localhost:49500/Learning/Chapitre.aspx?id=2")("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class with the URL and the use the [`Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx) property to get the query string part.

Once you have that string, do `String.Split` on the '&' character. For each string in the resulting array, do `String.Split` on the `'='` char. In the resulting array, the first string is the query parameter name, the second is the value (if present). Check if the name is the one you are interested in and if it is, get the value.

**Update**: Boy, I haven't touched VB since 1999... :-)

Here's the code for my answer. I didn't realize that the Url you want to parse is the page Url. For that specific case, `Request.QueryString("id")` will indeed be a better solution.

```
    Dim url As Uri = New Uri("http://localhost:49500/Learning/Chapitre.aspx?id=2")
    Dim query As String = url.Query.Trim("?")
    Dim parameters() As String = query.Split("&")
    Dim tokens() As String
    Dim value As String = ""
    For index As Integer = 0 To parameters.Length - 1
        tokens = parameters(index).Split("=")
        If tokens(0).ToLower = "id" Then
            If tokens.Length = 2 Then
                value = tokens(1)
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    ' At this point value contains the parameter value or
    ' is empty if the parameter has no value or if the parameter is not present
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request vb method 
Using the url  : http://localhost:49500/Learning/Chapitre.aspx?id=2

```
Dim valueId = Request("id")
```

to test the code:

```
response.Write(valueId)
```

value Id is 2