# How to extract a value from a URL query string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get individual query parameters from Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884551/get-individual-query-parameters-from-uri)

I have got a URL like this:

http://somedomain.com/website/webpage.aspx?token=123456&language=English

My goal is to extract 123456 from it. There can only be one payment ID in the query-string parameter. What kind of regular expression can I use? I am using C# (.NET) by the way.

Thanks

Comment: Check out [System.Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) and [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get url parameters from a string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659887/get-url-parameters-from-a-string-in-net)

Comment: @Cœur - right, thanks for letting us know.

Comment: @VVV yet, you didn't add your vote and your question is still open. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`token=(\d+)` should do the trick

To cater for aplhas as well you can do either:

`token=([a-zA-Z0-9+/=]+)` to explicitly match on the characters you expect.  This matches "token=" and then captures all following characters that match the character class, that is, a-z, A-Z, 0-9, +, / and =.

or

`token=([^&#]+)` to match any character except for the ones you know can finish the token.  This matches "token=" and then captures all characters until the first `&`, `#` or the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks. By the way token can contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, /, =

Comment: @VVV: How about `[?&]token=([^&]*)` then?

Comment: Do not use regex to parse urls in C#!

Comment: @Andrew Cooper - Can you explain that regular expression. It works correctly.

Comment: @Macek - My situation is little different and I need to use regular expression to extract this.

Comment: @VVV, there's nothing special about the situation you described in your question. If your situation is different than the one you posted, please post your *actual* situation.

Comment: http://somedomain.com/website/webpage.aspx?token=+++++//&language=English, from here I want extract ++++++// but if you use inbuilt .net methods for url parsing -> it automatically converts them to space and / will be converted to something like %3f etc.

Comment: Also when a token has a + symbol, I can actually mean + (not a space). Now this is not right because instead of + sign in my URL - I should have had %2b instead. But the URL is not under my control.

Comment: @macek - I tested your code. If the payment id is ++++//=, I only get "    //". + character is getting converted to space.

Comment: @VVV, oh, so you're saying your URL is not encoded properly? ok :P

Comment: @ Macek - the real problem is that the URL is in incorrect format but our code has no control over it and we just have to deal with it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @VVV - I've added some explanation to my answer

Answer (score 7):

Use System.URI class

The [Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx) property of the URI class returns the entire query as a string

```
Uri bUri = new Uri("http://somedomain.com/website/webpage.aspx
                    ?token=123456&language=English");

var query = bUri.Query.Replace("?", "");
```

Now query will have the string value `"token=123456&language=English"`

Then use LINQ to produce a Dictionary from the query attributes

```
var queryValues = query.Split('&').Select(q => q.Split('='))
                   .ToDictionary(k => k[0], v => v[1]);
```

You can then access the values as

```
queryValues["token"]
```

which will give you 123456

Answer (score 3):

Do not use regex for this. C# has built-in methods for this!

```
var queryString = string.Join(string.Empty, url.Split('?').Skip(1));
System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString)
```

[See more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884551/get-individual-query-parameters-from-uri)

Comment: I'd rather use `System.Uri` rather than `Split` to get the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
(?:token=)(?<TokenValue>[^&]+)
```

and in C# get *just* the value by:

```
myMatch.Groups["TokenValue"].Value
```

Comment: Do not use regex to parse urls in C#!

Comment: @macek I use, and advise one to use the System.URI class as with your answer. But I use and teach how to use Regex to do general parsing. The OP asked for a regex solution; to wit I provided. There are times such as when system.uri or xml link is not available, just as when a limited .Net client profile (as found in Silverlight). I figured the OP was either running a version where URL processing is not provided or running a thin .Net client, or using this as an example to *learn* regular expressions. To that end, I answered in a regex.