# How can i extract times from specific string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, winforms

My code is:

```
htmltoextract = new Uri("http://test");

client = new WebClient();
f = client.DownloadString(htmltoextract);
client.Dispose();
string pattern = @"(\d{12})";
Regex ex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);

MatchCollection matches = ex.Matches(f);
IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
List<DateTime> dateTime = new List<DateTime>();
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
     dateTime.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(match.Value, "yyyyMMddHHmm", provider));
}
```

Inside `f` somewhere inside i have this line:

```
var imageUrls = ["/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102145&ir=false","/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102130&ir=false","/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102115&ir=false","/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102100&ir=false","/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102045&ir=false","/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102030&ir=false","/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102015&ir=false","/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102000&ir=false","/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501101945&ir=false"];
```

I need to extract it twice to two Lists:

The first List is dateTime

The second List should be string and it should add it to it:

```
/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102145&ir=false
/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102130&ir=false
/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102115&ir=false
/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102100&ir=false
/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102045&ir=false
/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102030&ir=false
/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102015&ir=false
/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501102000&ir=false
/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501101945&ir=false
```

I have Two problems:

**How do I extract the times and the strings  /image2.ashx?region=is&time=201501101945&ir=false**

**how do I extract it all only from the part:var imageUrls = ["........**

Since inside `f` there are other places with this times I need to extract it only from the part start from var imageUrls = [" and end with "];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do. Its not a purist solution, but it works.

(below assumes that your data format remains exactly the same for a reasonable period of time. If the people managing the source change, this code will break!)

1. Do a regex match for the pattern "var imageUrls = [ ... ];" and move it to a seperate string.
2. From this, chop off the `var imageUrls = [` and `];` from the string.

Path A:

3. Using `string.split()`, create an array of the url strings.
4. Run a for-loop through the strings and assign them to the Uri class (eg: `myUri`). You can now get the value portion of each query string variable through `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(myUri.Query).Get("time");`

Path B:

3. Also chop off the "/image2.ashx?region=is&time=" and "&ir=false" leaving only what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Use HtmlAgilityPack to get Html and extract particular `<script>` tag.
- likely that script block can be matched with just reg-ex or even basic `String.IndexOf` to cut out list of urls
- with just list of Urls use `String.Split` to cut into unique once
- For each Url use Uri class to extract `Uri.Query` portion and than [Get individual query parameters from Uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884551/get-individual-query-parameters-from-uri)

Note: If JavaScript is too complicated you may need to get real JavaScript parser...

Answer (score 0):

To match the time use:

```
(?!/image2\.ashx\?region=is&time)\d+(?=&ir=false)
```

[DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F!%2Fimage2%5C.ashx%5C%3Fregion%3Dis%26time)%5Cd%2B(%3F%3D%26ir%3Dfalse)&i=%2Fimage2.ashx%3Fregion%3Dis%26time%3D201501102145%26ir%3Dfalse%0D%0A%2Fimage2.ashx%3Fregion%3Dis%26time%3D201501102130%26ir%3Dfalse%0D%0A%2Fimage2.ashx%3Fregion%3Dis%26time%3D201501102115%26ir%3Dfalse%0D%0A%2Fimage2.ashx%3Fregion%3Dis%26time%3D201501102100%26ir%3Dfalse%0D%0A%2Fimage2.ashx%3Fregion%3Dis%26time%3D201501102045%26ir%3Dfalse%0D%0A%2Fimage2.ashx%3Fregion%3Dis%26time%3D201501102030%26ir%3Dfalse%0D%0A%2Fimage2.ashx%3Fregion%3Dis%26time%3D201501102015%26ir%3Dfalse%0D%0A%2Fimage2.ashx%3Fregion%3Dis%26time%3D201501102000%26ir%3Dfalse%0D%0A%2Fimage2.ashx%3Fregion%3Dis%26time%3D201501101945%26ir%3Dfalse)